# parenthesis in python 3.7 are red and I think it keeps throwing me a Syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, macos

the inside brackets within a string keep turning red and I think its giving me a syntax error, specifically the first print statement when I run it in the terminal command prompt.

```
 print(f"Hi {user_name}, Im the {script} script")
                                               ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Ive tried googling it, replacing brackets(trial and error) and tried youtube, thought this would work better

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name=argv
prompt="> "

print(f"Hi {user_name}, im the {script} script")
print("Id like to ask you a few questions")
print(f"do you like me {user_name}?")
likes=input(prompt)

print(f"where do you live {user_name}?")
lives=input(prompt)

print("what kind of computer do you have?")
computer=input(prompt)

print(f"""
Alright, so you said {likes} about liking me.
You live in {lives}. Not sure where that is.
And you have a {computer} computer. Nice
""")
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the exact error message?

Comment: Unless you are seeing a `SyntaxError` while running code, this can be more or less a problem with your editor.

Comment: @gilch, I just edited it to show where its fudging up.

Comment: @Austin, I am getting a syntax error, hope its not with the editor but is it possible a post-installed package might mess something up?

Comment: Can you copy-paste the error message as it is without manually typing it? When you manually do it, you make mistakes like `'Im'` vs `'im'`.

Comment: I did copy n paste it, I did the exercise word for word and period for period AND several trial and error tests but like I said im thinking it could be a 'bracket manager' problem.

Comment: It seems the problem is you are using an older version where `f` strings are not supported. Hence you have to be contented with using `.format`.

Answer (score 1):

You would not be getting that syntax error on Python 3.7. Most likely, you are attempting to run the script using an old version of Python that does not have the new f-string syntax.

On macOS, be aware that by default, the `python` command refers to Python version 2. Try running the script with `python3` instead.

If you just type in `python` at the terminal, the banner before the `>>>` prompt will tell you exactly what version it is. Same with `python3`.

Note that you must have at least version 3.6 to use f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only run into an error when you attempt to enter a name more than a word. So I made some adjustments. See if this was the case:

```
from sys import argv

script = argv[0]
if len(argv) < 2:
    print("you must give me a name as commandline param to work with")
    exit(0)
user_name=' '.join(argv[1:])
prompt="> "

print(f"Hi {user_name}, im the {script} script")
print("Id like to ask you a few questions")
print(f"do you like me {user_name}?")
likes=input(prompt)

print(f"where do you live {user_name}?")
lives=input(prompt)

print("what kind of computer do you have?")
computer=input(prompt)

print(f"""
Alright, so you said {likes} about liking me.
You live in {lives}. Not sure where that is.
And you have a {computer} computer. Nice
""")
```

Comment: @Austin, I copy n pasted it n ran it but I got another syntax error in the same place. the instructor was using version 3.6 instead of 3.7(which im using) so you might be on two something with the F strings not being supported

Comment: @Philbus, I'm not sure if your comment was directed towards my solution but I'd like to add that mine was run on python 3.6 and it works fine

Comment: I tried replacing  the f with .format and python3 with python, same bummer results

Comment: Can you make sure that you are not running python 2 ? I'm running into the problem you've described whenever I try to run it with python27. So, please make sure of that.

Comment: BRO THAT WORKED! I replaced it with 3.7 and ran it in the terminal and its asking me for input, thank you guys, I appreciate all the help

Comment: My pleasure! Please update your question referring to the cause and measures for future reference

Comment: @Philbus please consider marking Faisal Rahman Avash's answer as accepted (check mark on the left) since it worked for you.